# SVN merge issue

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, out-of-memory, svn-merge

I am trying to do svn merge from some branch to my local workspace.

When I try to do merge, it takes lot of time and stops abruptly.

Second time, I opened windows task manager and started the merge procedure again. I find that, fewminute after starting merge, PF usage rises drastically causing the system very slow and out of PF memory. Hence the program crashes.

Next I tried with '--dry-run' and '--ignore-ancestry' options together, it was completing successfully. But on removing --dry-run option, again same story of crashing the application.

I am using svn 1.6.0 client on windows OS.

I am suspecting if there is anything to do with the repository or structure.
Please suggest me if I am missing anything.

Comment: Is your client the cmd line client, and is the version number correct? If both are yes, upgrade to at least the last 1.6.x version which is currently 1.6.20 (see the [Collabnet Download](http://www.collab.net/downloads/svn-other) for a version)

Comment: I have tried with: svn command line 1.6.0, tortoise SVN 1.6.0 and tortoise SVN 1.6.16
My server is svn 1.6.18 on redhat linux configured wtih NTLM auth. 

I am using 1.6.0 because the higher version (TSVN 1.6.16) was having problem workiong with this repo.